# VirtualHosting through Apache Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am having the domain(any three) and want that it should run with the same port that the tomcat is having(8080). I have done upto that the adding the domain name and appbase in **SERVER.XML**.

```
    <Host name="www.hello.com"  appBase="hello_webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>

<Host name="www.hi.com"  appBase="hi_webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>

<Host name="www.bye.com"  appBase="bye_webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
```

and change in the host file of etc

```
 xxx.xxx.x.xx www.hello.com
 xxx.xxx.x.xx www.hi.com
 xxx.xxx.x.xx www.bye.com
```

XXX.XXX.X.XX is the ip address
but by running www.hello.com:8080,it is giving the error 404.

Comment: where did you put your apps content ?

Comment: I have copy the webapps folder three times and give the name of appBase i.e.hello_webapps, hi_webapps and bye_webapps.The webApps folder are there in the main folder where we find the bin,conf,webapps,log,lib.....

Comment: I have find my answer...there was the problem with the root folder.That the root folder should have the file/war file of the project that we want to run

Comment: that's good , congrats :)

Answer (score 0):

There are tree essentials part TODO to establish virtual hosting in tomcat :

- DNS configuration

You have to prepare your domain names and IP and configure your DNS server,the alternative is to   use hosts file for test/dev .

- Server.xml configuration

this step is to map deployed apps folder with the domain names  that will be used when  requesting the Tomcat server

example from official doc :

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="ren">
    <Host name="ren"    appBase="renapps"/>
    <Host name="stimpy" appBase="stimpyapps"/>
</Engine>
```

- Deploiement appliction folder

put the content of your app inside a folder called **ROOT** which will be inside the folder used in server.xml configuration (renapps in the example, the content will be in `renapps/ROOT/` )

Comment: we donot have to add the path in the etc/hosts

Comment: are you saying that i have to create the hi_webapps,bye_webapps and hello_webapps in the root folder of the webapps

Comment: you have to create   inside the hello_webapps and other a ROOT folder , and put inside it the content of your app

Comment: @programmer your folders hi_webapps,bye_webapps and hello_webapps should be in the same folder as the default webapps.